# Getting the model inside a controller emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I need to get the grand total price of all the objects returned from a JSON API.

my idea is to create a controller and set a property on it. Then grab the model loop over each object and add to the predefined property that objects total price. Something like this:

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    orderTotal: 0,

    getOrderTotal: function(){
        var model = this.get('model');

        model.forEach(function(c){
            var order_total = this.get('orderTotal') * c.total_price;
            this.set('orderTotal', order_total)
        });
    }
});
```

problem is I can't get the model. How can I access the model inside a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is probably loaded asynchronously, therefore you will have to use .then(...) to wait for the model being loaded.

```
this.get('model').then(function(data) { ... create sum using `data` });
```

Though I would use computed properties to create the sum of something that can potentially change:

```
allPrices: Ember.computed.mapBy('model', 'price'),
totalPrice: Ember.computed.sum('allPrices')
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wiwiqulozi/1/