# Retrieving model's property in controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a model which contains a single data but it's inside an array. I want to retrieve this data from inside my controller and making it a property of the controller so I can use it in other controllers. For example :

```
App.CurrentsubuserController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({

    currentsubuser: function() {
       return this.get('model'); <-------** not working **
    }.property()

});
```

Basically I want to get the whole associated model so I can access it's datas. What is the syntax I have to use? Thank you

Comment: So do you want access to the model's RecordArray or just the single item in the array from other controllers?

Comment: one other note is that you'll likely want to move away from `Ember.ArrayController` if this is a new project. See https://gist.github.com/samselikoff/1d7300ce59d216fdaf97

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure of what your goal is here, but from another controller you can do a `someAttribute: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.someController.model')`

There is no need to create any local attribute in the controller that is being provided model data unless you are transforming it in some way.

You will need to specify a `needs` in that controller to reference the one you are pulling model data from like (*adjust for your global style javascript*)

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['someController'],
  someAttr: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.someController.model')
})
```

I know that will work fine, but thats not to say you *should* be doing any of this. And, obviously, make sure the model data is in the originating controller as you expect. A quick way to validate this is tossing a logging helper into your handlebars like `{{log model}}` or using the Ember Inspector in the browser.

**UPDATE**: Based on your comment below, this will work

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  currentSubUser: Ember.computed.readOnly('model.firstObject'),
})
```

Then, in your template you can use `{{ currentSubUser.foo }}`

Comment: In my template I am using {{#each current in model}} to display model's attribute because the currensubuser is passed by a json array which contains a single data so I have to use an each loop even if there is a single data. I just want to be able to use, for example, {{currentsubuser}} to display my data instead of doing an each loop. That's why I want to retrieve model's attributes in a property.

Comment: See my updated answer. I did some testing and that may be a little cleaner approach and allow you to control the access if you ever want to transform the data before other controllers/templates access it. Obviously you could replace the `readOnly` with `alias`, if you want to be able to edit the value for some reason.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks to you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:
[Getting the model inside a controller emberjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30628995/getting-the-model-inside-a-controller-emberjs)

Basically the model is loaded asynchronously. You can use `this.get('model').then(function(data) { ... })` to work with the data, once it's loaded. Although I suggest using Ember.computed macros, like .mapBy:

```
currentsubuser: Ember.computed.mapBy('model', 'subuserproperty')
```

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html#method_mapBy

Comment: Will try this and keep updating.

Comment: I don't think I can use mapBy because I actually don't want to filter the datas by properties, I just want to retrieve all of them (which is a single data) and set it as controller property. I tried using this.get('model').then(function(data){
   return data.firstObject; but it is not working.

Comment: Here is what I did, I mapped  a property using mapBy for each attribute in the model. Then I retrieve it by calling : this.get('controllers.currentsubuser').get('propertyName')[0], because it is an array. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to store the model into an attribute.

Check this about the [dependencies between controllers](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/).

But to answer your question, do so:

On the controller you want to retrieve the ** CurrentsubuserController** model you define the need of this controller:

```
export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    needs: "currentsubusercontroller"
    currentSubUserController: Ember.computed.alias("controllers.CurrentsubuserController")
});
```

And then you can access this controller and his model with `this.get('currentSubUserController.model')`

Comment: I think you are giving me a good advice. But I'd need some more information. My model has a single data passed by a json array and I basically want to retrieve this data in another controller. I tried this.get('model').firstObject but no luck. Do you know how I could do that? Thank you for your time

Comment: this.get('currentSubUserController') returns your controller?